# How to set the principle for optional one-to-one using Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

```
public class Sale
{
   public int SaleId { get; set; }
   public Comment Comment { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
   public int CommentId { get; set; }
   public int SaleId { get; set; }

   public Sale Sale { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
   .HasRequired(s => s.Sale)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(s => s.SaleId);
```

And yet, its got it the wrong way around...

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("public.tbl_sale", "Comment_CommentId", c => c.Long());
    AddForeignKey("public.tbl_sale", "Comment_CommentId", "public.tbl_comment", "CommentId");
}
```

How fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of modelling such relationship in EF is to use [Shared Primary Key Association](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations).

In order to do that, remove the `SaleId` from the `Comment` class (remember - the `CommentId` will be both PK and FK) and use the following configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
   .HasRequired(c => c.Sale)
   .WithOptional(s => s.Comment);
```

Comment: You are both correct: I manually deleted my database and checked the answer. Thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: That makes sense. Currently when I use that builder code, it tries dropping the CommentId column and promoting SaleId to the primary key!

Comment: I think my database design is SMELLY.